# Pros and cons of using Windows containers instead of Linux containers for Docker?

Tags: docker, windows-10

I'm installing Docker for Windows (CE) on Windows 10 and the first screen asks me:

> [  ] Use Windows containers instead of Linux containers (this can be changed after installation)

This seems an important decision, yet the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/), [FAQ](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/) and [Windows container tutorial](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/windows/windows-containers/README.md) provides no information about *why* I might choose one over the other.

It would be helpful to have an objective overview of the ramifications of this choice:

- Will one option be faster than the other?
- Does the decision affect usage of system resources (RAM, CPU)?
- Can I run the same images on both types?
- Is one more secure than the other?

Any other distinctions that might help me reach a conclusion would be very welcome.

Comment: The answer to this is not opinion based. And it is accepted. So no need to close this one.

Comment: I think that a better answer to what the OP really wanted to know (although possibly didn't ask it so precisely) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080376/261332, or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080526/261332 (they are both in the same question)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You HAVE to use a windows host for windows containers, however you can use either a Linux host or a Windows host for Linux containers. [Since April 2018 you can even run both in parallel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/04/20/running-docker-windows-and-linux-containers-simultaneously/).

> Will one option be faster than the other?

No. faster at what?

> Does the decision affect usage of system resources (RAM, CPU)?

Windows uses more resources than Linux - Windows Nano is as small as it gets

> Can I run the same images on both types?

No. you can run .NET apps in mono containers but you cannot start a windows container on a Linux host and vice versa - it's not the same as virtualization

> Is one more secure than the other?

Again - more secure at what? No.
They both run native Docker so it's nothing like hyper-v vs VMware and more like Linux vs Windows so it all depends on what you are going to run .net, python, java, ruby etc.

Comment: Second this. The read complement this answer https://containerjournal.com/2016/10/28/linux-vs-windows-containers-whats-difference/

Comment: So if I select to use Linux containers, Docker will fire up a Hyper-V Linux VM to run my containers, otherwise it will run Windows containers natively? And I can't run both types of container concurrently?

Comment: docker for windows 10 allows you to do this - but in production you would have a docker swarm with Linux and Windows hosts

Comment: Docker is based on lxc (Linux) - it will use the same kernel as the Docker-host. If you start windows in a lxc it has to virtualize or emulate win. Not sure if the same applies to win-docker, since win supports linux.

Comment: @DuncanJones, just 3 days after you asked there was a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/04/20/running-docker-windows-and-linux-containers-simultaneously/) on MSDN explaining that you now CAN run Windows and Linux containers in parallel.

Comment: This answer doesn't clear much up for me. Do Windows containers also run in separate Hyper-V VMs? Is it as simple as "windows images require windows containers, linux images require linux containers"?

Comment: yes they 'also' run in lightweight hyper-v vms. but, their natural design is a chroot environment which is isolated or 'contained' but using the same kernel, e.g. not running in it's own OS with hardware emulation, i.e. virtualization. Microsoft now offer 'process isolated' containers which share the same kernel as the host and do not require a separate virtual machine - as to the requirements - it's kernel fork and chroot'ed environment essentially, so the requirements of the host are a running Windows/Linux kernel, you can't fork a Linux kernel and run Windows and vice versa :-)

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin put that in the answer

Comment: @OrangeDog - That wasn't the question